# How to get a type="submit" button to also include an href action

Tags: html

So basically I have this submit button that saves a page during an edit.

What I want it to do is also visit an href link after the submit happens. What this href will do is clear my site's cache, and once this is done, the submit goes through and the save occurs.

Here's what I attempted but it isn't working:

```
<form action="tiki-admin_system.php?do=all" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="wikiaction btn btn-primary" title="{tr}Save the page.{/tr}" name="save" value="{tr}Save{/tr}" onclick="needToConfirm=false;">
</form>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to use javascript or jquery solution ?

Comment: Preferably not. I'd like a solution that would work even for users without JS enabled

Answer (score 0):

You have to do what you want from the server side. Edit your script `tiki-admin_system.php` to make it 'clear the cache' before doing what it should do.

Comment: Would I put the code to 'clear the cache' just before this submit button? Or should it be within a certain tag?

Comment: It should be in the code that handles the input of the form (In your code the form has only a submit button, so all what you get is whether form is submitted or not). In this code you would insert the code that clears the cache before the existing code.